# Plotly and preventing axis from disappearing during rotation

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating a 3D scatterplot using plotly. All is good with the visual, except when rotating the cube which is formed the axis flip to the other side and/or are cut. Below is an image of where the axis on the left side is being cut from the image. Is there a way to make a cube without the need for the axis being cut? There is probably a simple solution for this

The below I have updated from the initial question:

[image]
By moving the plot around in the viewer, at times the axes moves to the top (as in the image) or sometimes the full axis is not visible. I want the values on the axis to be visible together with the axis not shifting and remaining in the same place. I also a reproducible example below

```
library(plotly)

test_plot<-plot_ly(x=mtcars$disp, y=mtcars$mpg, 
                         z=mtcars$cyl,type="scatter3d", mode="markers",
                         color=mtcars$carb, marker = list(size = 4),colors = c("blue", "red"))%>% layout(
                           title = "Test",
                           xaxis = list(showgrid = T),
                           yaxis = list(gridcolor = "black"),
                           scene = list(
                             xaxis = list(title = "disp"),
                             yaxis = list(title = "mpg"),
                             zaxis = list(title = "cyl")))

test_plot
```

Comment: Could you add sample data, so your code will run?  It doesn't need to be the full `comb_data`, just something similar that will illustrate the problem for someone else.

Comment: Added a reproducible exam ple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking for, I think at least some parts of it are impossible.  The reason `plotly` moves the axis labels is because for certain orientations of the plot, the initial axis will overlap and obscure the data, or (as in your posted example), it will overlap and obscure labels on another axis.  For other orientations, the data will overlap and obscure the axis.

You also mention (and your original example showed) that in some orientations, parts of the axis disappear.  I'm having trouble reproducing this with the current dataset, but looking at your original plot (still visible at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63056649/revisions), it looks as though there's a small miscalculation in `plotly`, and the labels are being clipped when they shouldn't.

For what it's worth, `plotly` does a better job with axis labels than `rgl`, though `rgl` does allow the axes to be fixed in a specific location.  If that's really what you want, you might consider switching to that package.

Comment: Thank you I will give rgl a go